Remove all key bindings in Windows Terminal
I'm running WSL2 in the Windows Terminal (v. 1.19, Windows 11). I don't need any of the key bindings (I want to reserve them for tmux, vim etc).
I can remove a single key binding by writing in the json config:
"actions": 
    [
        {
            "command": "unbound",
            "keys": "ctrl+shift+p"
        },
    ]

Or I can delete a shortcut by clicking on the change and remove icons in the terminal settings tab?
Both is tiresome with 40+ shortcuts. Is there a way to discard everything at once or get a list of all shortcuts to put in the JSON?
